# Embedding Marketing Cloud forms on HTML pages

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm very familiar with setting up a CloudPage to capture data into a data extension, but I can't find the right resources for embedding a form outside of CloudPages.

If I'm looking to create a form (name, title, and email) on an HTML website that already exists, what is the best way to send that form data into a data extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can use DEManager to add information via a web form to a data extension instead of a subscriber list. The functionality acts similarly to the Web Collect form, but the sample code uses different tags to place information in the data extension.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_demanager.htm&type=5

A more complex solution would be leveraging Marketing Cloud API Asynchronously Insert Data Extension with a back-end service like JAVA, Node, etc.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/insertDataExtensionIDAsync.htm

Comment: DEManager is exactly what I was looking for. Tested and works perfectly within the site. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iFrame to include your form on an external website, once filled in, will populate the data correctly into your DE:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Tested and working.