# External landing page for newsletter sign-up - how would I send a confirmation email using API event?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I have been creating an external landing page (not on Salesforce) with a form to let contact sign-up to a newsletter service. The form of this landing page will be connected to a DE in Marketing Cloud. I have the necessity then to send immediately an email confirmation to those contacts who have signed up for the newsletter service.
I know automation run every 1 hour, but I would need something that's immediate and that send the confirmation email as soon as the contact sign up.
How would I achieve this? By using an API event - but how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I get this right then you have an external form which is already using form action to send data back to marketing cloud data extensions using a cloud page.

i would recommend you to go ahead modify the page to accommodate below steps

- create one journey using API entry event
- use email activity as next step for auto responder
- create one installed APP
- modify the cloud page to authorize and let it communicate with the journey's API entry event
- inject relevant data in to Journey API entry event as well

OR

simply use smartcapture form in your external page
setup journey but with cloud page submission as entry source followed by email activity

hope this helps

Comment: Hi @pragyanshu kukreti - the landing page has been build externally and it's not on Marketing Cloud - it is connected to Marketing Cloud with an embedded form which is connected to a Data Extension. Would the API event still doable? (I don't think the second option you've mentioned is doable). Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: can you elaborate how you are sending data to SFMC data xtensions?

Comment: Hi @pragyanshu kukreti with an embedded form created as POC https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/268136/embedding-marketing-cloud-forms-on-html-pages

Comment: Hi @pragyanshu kukreti What we need is to trigger an email to the user when they are added to a Data Extension using DEManager (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_demanager.htm&type=5).

Is there a way to send a welcome email using this method?

Comment: I am wondering why it shouldn't work. Have you tried it already and what is the issue you are encountering when using DEmanager method